# Why preload image don't work?

Tags: reactjs

I wrote a component for preload images. Every image have got a lite version (prop `previewUrl`) and normal version (prop `src`)
It seems, everything should be ok, but it's not!. Event `onload` doesn't work. `GET` request doesn't happend. I break my mind and don't know where the misstake.

Here is a codepen https://codepen.io/fsdev/pen/bLWgoL of the code below

```
class Image extends React.Component {

    constructor(props){
        super(props);
        this.state = { src: null };
        this.preloadImage = this.preloadImage.bind(this);
    }
    componentWillMount(){
        const { src: bigImage, previewUrl } = this.props;
        this.setState({src: previewUrl});
        this.preloadImage(bigImage)
            .then(() => {
                console.log("Loaded");
                this.setState({src: bigImage});
            })
            .catch(e => console.error(e.message))
    }
    preloadImage(url){
        return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
            const image = new Image();
            image.onload = resolve;
            image.onerror = reject;
            image.src = url;
        })
    }

    render(){
        const { src } = this.state;
        const { previewUrl, ...rest } = this.props;
        return(
            <img {...rest} src={src} />
        )
    }
}



class App extends React.Component {
  render(){ 
    return(

<Image src="http://res.cloudinary.com/playhs/image/upload/v1518304840/bsyjqxahzr8bmaxuvj04.png"
        previewUrl="http://res.cloudinary.com/playhs/image/upload/q_30/v1518304850/ztpj7gnqazk6ng2tzamk.jpg"
        />

    )
  }

}

ReactDOM.render(
  <App/>, document.body
)
```

Thank you

Answer (score 0):

I'am stupid
My React Component called as `Image`
and here

```
const image = new Image();
```

I call here my own Component :) lol